# Architectures for a Java web application

Tags: java, architecture

What are the different architectures for developing professional and organized Java Web Applications? I have heard about MVC architecture, what architecture else does, for example, Stackoverflow, google, orkut, etc.. use for a scalable, robust and easily-maintainable-from-the-developers-point-of-view, exist!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Quite honestly, most "web applications" are probably written in PHP.

Anyway read up on web frameworks, but to get you started here is a list of the most widely used web framework (that I can think of).

```
Ruby : Rails
Python : Django
Java : Spring
C# : ASP.NET MVC
```

Then there are specialized things like `Google Web Toolkit` for writing Gmail like apps.

Personally I lean towards ASP.NET MVC and Django, but Rails and Spring are pretty good as well.

But there is a LOT more than just the web framework for many of these applications. Lots of AJAX, Javascript, Flash, scripting, etc. etc.

But definitely start using one of the above 4 (or 5 if you need GWT).

Comment: -1 Because this answer has nothing to do with Ajay's question, he asks about Architectures in a Java environment, this answer answers the usual simple "How can i create my own Web-Application, i have no idea how to do this!1!11one"... no offense! :-)

Comment: Wow way to give me a thumbs down! He clearly asks "What architecture does Stackoverflow google orkut, etc" use. This clearly is not specific to Java. Stackoverflow is in ASP.NET MVC.

Answer (score 0):

Personally I like [Spring MVC](http://static.springsource.org/spring/docs/2.0.x/reference/mvc.html) for both small or big things. Using frameworks takes a lot of the hassle out when creating a java web app.

Apache Struts used to be (years ago) very popular and the few times I wrote some sort of small web framework it always resembled the Struts patterns for some reason. So it could be a good idea to look at some of these frameworks first and if you later on still want to create your own keep the framework you liked the most in mind.

Answer (score 0):

(I wonder why people name framework to person asking for architecture.)

1) I would recommend starting thinking about layered architecture. One Layer should know about (depend on) only 1 nearest layer.

```
Presentation
Domain
Persistence
```

Where Presentation (UI) and Persistence (database) , depend on Domain.

[Describe the architecture you use for Java web applications?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/286846/describe-the-architecture-you-use-for-java-web-applications)

2) Take some ideas from DDD ([Domain-Driven Design](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Domain-driven_design)). Reading of [Eric Evans book](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/0321125215) is recommended.

Answer (score -1):

After trying a lot of different java web frameworks, I’m really argent to recommend [grails](http://www.grails.org/). Only 1-2 hours you need to try it out and to build you test web application. After a short time you are able to decide if it suitable for your requirements.

Comment: While Grails is quite interesting to learn. I am to warn, that it is based on Groovy, that is good but a bit different from Java.

Answer (score -3):

Read up on design patterns:

[Wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Design_pattern_(computer_science)#Classification_and_list)

Comment: Interesting how an answer suggesting rails, django, and asp.net gets voted up when the OP asked a general question about dev models for a Java application.

Comment: Generic "go read X" answers without any description of why are frowned upon here, which I think is good.